# Self Referencing JSON Object

Tags: json, ember.js, fetch

I have a JSON object from an API that seems a bit tricky. I need to reference parts of the object with other parts. See below for some more context. I need the InboundLegId to reference the ID in the Legs object. Any ideas here?

[image]

I'm calling this API via Fetch, and inside Itineraries you get the price of a flight, in order to get more details on that flight, you need to reference it's 'Leg' via Id (outboundLegId/InboundLegId).

Comment: why not use JSON:API? With JSON:API you can do exactly this with relationships.

Comment: I'm sorry, what is the question? Are you getting an error? Is there something you need to do with this api response? Please be very specific.

Comment: I'm calling this API via Fetch, and inside Itineraries you get the price of a flight, in order to get more details on that flight, you need to reference it's 'Leg' via Id (outboundLegId/InboundLegId).

@Lux any tips on using JSON:API with fetch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can edit your json response just like any other plain old javascript object:

```
fetch(...).then(json => {
  json.Itineraries.forEach(itinerary => {
    itinerary.InboundLeg = json.Legs.find(leg => leg.Id === itinerary.InboundLegId);
  });

  // you can now access json.Intineraries[0].InboundLeg.Arrival

  // rest of your code using the json here.
});
```